# ImportError : Attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, pylint

I am learning to program with python and I am having issues with importing from a module in a package. I am usingvisual studio code with Python 3.8.2 64 bit.

[My Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQZhP.png)

```
.vscode
├── ecommerce
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── database.py
│   ├── products.py
│   └── payments
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── authorizenet.py
│       └── paypal.py
├── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

in the `ecommerce/products.py` file I have:

```py
#products.py
from .database import Database
p = Database(3,2)
```

So that I can import the `Database` class from the `ecommerce/database.py` file. But I get error

```
ImportError : Attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: you should also specify from which location you are running the module

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems, from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and experimenting, that relative imports (involving ., .. etc) only work if

1. the importing module has a `__name__` other than `__main__`, and further,
2. the `__name__` of the importing module is pkg.module_name, i.e., it has to be imported from above in the directory hierarchy (to have a parent pkg as part of it's `__name__`.)

OR

the importing module is being specified via module syntax  that includes a parent pkg as `python -m pkg.module`, in which case it's `__name__` is still `__main__`, so it is being run as a script, yet relative imports will work. Here `__package__` is set and used to find the parent package while `__name__` is `__main__`; [more here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/#proposed-change).

[After all that, it appears that `__package__` and `sys.path` are key to determining if/how relative imports work. `__name__` indicates script or module(i.e., `__main__` or `module_name`). `__package__` indicates where in the package the relative imports occur with respect to, and the top of `__package__` needs to be in `sys.path`.]

So, continuing with @AmitTendulkar 's example,  if you run this as `> python main.py` or `> python -m main` or `> python -m ecommerce.products` from the project root directory, or enter interactive python from that root directory and `import main`, or `import ecommerce.products` the relative imports in products.py will work.

But if you `> python products.py` or `> python -m products` from within ecommerce directory, or enter interactive python from that ecommerce directory and `import products` they will fail.

It is helpful to add

```
print("In module products __package__, __name__ ==", __package__, __name__)
```

etc. in each file to debug.

UPDATE:

How imports work depend on `sys.path` and `__package__`, not on `__name__`.
Issued from `/home/jj`, `> python sub/mod.py` has a `sys.path`, `__package__` of `/home/jj/sub`, `None` -absolute imports of modules in `sys.path` work, relative imports fail.

`> python -m sub.mod` has  `sys.path`, `__package__` of `/home/jj`, `sub` -absolute imports of modules in `sys.path` work, relative imports work relative to `sys.path` + `__package__`.

It is more helpful to add

```
import sys    
print("In module products sys.path[0], __package__ ==", sys.path[0], __package__)
```

etc. in each file to debug.

Comment: Indeed, I found that I need **all of** 1) putting an `__init__.py` in the top dir of my code **and** 2) adding the parent directory of the top dir to my `PYTHONPATH` **and** 3) setting the `__package__` variable in my Python program to the name of the directory that contains `__init__.py`.

Comment: Sounds similar to boilerplate described in the fourth paragraph under Proposed Changes of the ‘more here’ link. If your invoking as > python code.py, does invoking as  > python -m dir.code eliminate need for 2) and 3) as in my UPDATE?

Comment: Sort of; I need to adapt the relative imports slightly and after what looks like a succesful run, I get `python3: Error while finding module specification for 'dir.code.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'dir.code' while trying to find 'dir.code.py')`.

Comment: Point 1. above was very useful for me (importing module must have `__name__` other than `__main__`). I was running into this import issue with an otherwise "correctly" laid out package, but didn't realize that executing a module as a script would screw up local imports. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

Since you are using Python 3.8 version, the imports work a little differently, but I think this should work:

Use either:

```
from database import Database
#Database is the class
```

or try:

```
import database.Database
```

lastly, this one is very secure and best practice possibly:

```
from . import Database  
# The '.' (dot) means from within the same directory as this __init__.py module grab the Database class.
```

Comment: "the imports work a little differently" In what way? I cannot reproduce OP's problem (imports work fine) and your solutions don't work, resulting in `ModuleNotFoundError`, while I'm using Python 3.8.3. What am I not seeing?
This post confused me a lot while trying to understand the import system.
My `__init__.py` is empty btw.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports shows that what the OP is trying to do should work.

Comment: @Jupiter, it should work, but it doesn't for me on 3.8.5. Interestingly, pylance running in VSCode does resolve the imports when written as in the last two snippets, so I get code completion, but when I try running the code, it complains, `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Only the first snippet works for me, but then pylance fails

Comment: @Im guessing here but that might have something to do with that pylance might invoke python from a different working directly than when you run the code yourself.

Comment: why there's not 'right' answer for this issue in python community ?

Comment: @Arseny, you can use the first snippet and still have VSCode resolving your imports by using VSCode's multi-root workspace and add an extra path: 
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./<otherroot>"
    ] to the settings.json.

Comment: 'readability counts' also: import file from file.... I feel like im taking crazy pills.

Comment: @BeyhanGul, Python imports are very convoluted and get worse over time.  At this point, C `#include`s are better...

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/2760299) answer to be extremely helpful.

Comment: There is a right answer, and it's simple and has been clearly and straightforwardly explained many times. There are a lot of people asking similar questions because they do not properly understand how to characterize their exact situation, or because they read bad advice from other people who puzzled through a different setup without a proper understanding. At any rate, I can guarantee that the problem has **nothing to do with** Python 3.8.

Comment: @BeyhanGul because people like to create artificial boundaries like that to secure their jobs ... meaning that whoever designed this puzzle was really insecure

Comment: "from within the same directory as this __init__.py module grab the Database class." How can a class be within a directory, not within a .py file in a directory?

Comment: @idiot,  the dot `.` refers to the current directory, so it means the same directory as the current module where this code is written from ( the __init__.py this is the package file where the database is going to be imported from).

So, the Database class is located in a module within the same directory as the module where the code is written for this package.

Comment: @de_classified what if there are multiple modules in that directory? How does it know which .py file to open?

Comment: @idiot, you can have multiple modules but the statement `from . import Database` would go get the one with the `Database` import and if there are multiple `Database` imports (similar names) you could specify it more by doing `from nameofpyfile.module import Database` or even in that case you can do `import database.Database` basically the same thing.

Comment: @BeyhanGul cos Python is completely screwed up.

Answer (score 19):

i had a similar issue on Windows, and what helped me was (adapted to your directory):

```
# local imports
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\path\to\your\project")

from ecommerce.database import Database
```

Comment: This seems like such a hacky way of doing it but it works and makes the most sense.

Comment: @TannerDavis I agree it's not the most portable, but solves the issue for OP. I had to use this when the environment we developed  was significantly different to the one the script ran, so had to hardcode the location. For portability perhaps pathlib is better, declaring a root folder and append to path, using something like this:
```root_folder = r'{}'.format(pathlib.Path(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute().parent))```
 and here you'll have to figure out where exactly your modules are.

Comment: This works for me, ubuntu 18, python 3.8.1

Comment: Even easier and worked for me:`sys.path.append(os.getcwd())`, python 3.7.6

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me in Python 3.8.10

Answer (score 10):

Considering the below basic file structure

```
├── ecommerce
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── database.py
|   └── products.py
└── main.py
```

I am assuming you are running `python main.py` from the project root.

Here is the text copied from the Python tutorial that explains the basic rule around relative import,

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always `__main__`, modules intended for use as the main module of a  Python application must always use absolute imports.

So the below code will work,

```
# main.py
import ecommerce.products 
# or to use it directly 
# from ecommerce.products import my_product

ecommerce.products.my_product()
```

Your product.py might look like,

```
# ecommerce/products.py
from .database import Database

def my_product():
    p = Database(3, 2)
```

And database.py will look like below,

```
# ecommerce/database.py

class Database():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        print('Inside DB init')

    # Rest of the methods...
```

You will now get,

```
> python main.py
Inside DB init
```

Ideally the `__init__.py` file at root is not required as the package name is starting from ecommerce.

You can also run `python -m ecommerce.products` command to directly call products.py. But that won't yield any output as we are not calling the my_product() function (only defining it).

Calling `python ecommerce/products.py` will not work as the name of the current module will then become `__main__` and not `ecommerce`. The relative importing only works when used within the current package (so in your main script you always need to import your `ecommerce` package).

Answer (score 2):

To allow the use of relative imports, you need to "turn your code into a package".

This means **all of**:

1. putting an `__init__.py` in the top directory of your code (in your example `.vscode`)
2. adding the full (absolute) path to the parent directory of the top directory (i.e., the *parent* of your directory `.vscode`) to your `PYTHONPATH`
3. setting the `__package__` variable in your Python program to the name of the directory that contains `__init__.py`, in your case "`.vscode`".

You should then be able to use in `ecommerce/products.py`:

```
from .ecommerce.database import Database
```

I'm not sure why the dot is in the name `.vscode` - is that part of the directory name, or part of the lines in your directory tree?  If the latter, replace `.vscode` with `vscode` above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
from ecommerce.database import Database
```

Answer (score -2):

Presumably, you make executable the file "products.py", which violates the very concept of packages, the package ceases to be a package and relative import does not work. You must call this outside the package.

Here I am also not sure whether the root directory name can start with a dot like ".vscode".

Answer (score -3):

This may seem like a hack but it actually work, this happens because of bad package structure

In you case try importing

`from .vs_code.ecommerce import database`

Now wherever you want to call the class constructor do this:

`database.Database()`

you can assign this to a variable and use it.