# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package when running main.py

Tags: python, django, importerror

I am using Django 3.0 for my project and want to make a simple registration page. My registration information is not showing up on the admin database page. `python manage.py runserver` is not raising any errors but `admin.py` and `views.py` have import errors. I'm also sharing same code snippet. Here are some snippet of my admin.py, views.py, models.py and settings.py.

**error**

```
[Running] python -u "g:\Study\Python\Django Project\checkproject\checkapp\views.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Study\Python\Django Project\checkproject\checkapp\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import registerPerson
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import registerPerson

class register(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password']
admin.site.register(registerPerson,register)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import registerPerson

def register(request):
    return render(request,'registration.html')

def add_registration(request):
    firstname = request.POST["first_name"]
    lastname = request.POST["lastname"]
    email = request.POST["email"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    info = registerPerson(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, email=email, password=password)
    info.save()
    return render(request,'registration.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class registerPerson(models.Model):
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

**settings.py**

```
 ["""
    Django settings for checkProject project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.6.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
    """

    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    TEMPLATES_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'checkapp/templates')


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '6rst-p=7+k*hq*21uynw_rj)=s2iqh668_hun-vg7+!@#uni9o'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = \[\]


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = \[
        'checkapp.apps.CheckappConfig',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    \]

    MIDDLEWARE = \[
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    \]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'checkProject.urls'

    TEMPLATES = \[
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': \[TEMPLATES_DIR\],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': \[
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                \],
            },
        },
    \]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'checkProject.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = \[
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    \]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**here is my project tree structure**

```
CHECKPROJECT
    checkapp
        _pycache
        migrations
        templates
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    checkProject
        __pycache__
        __init__.py
        asgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

Comment: Please provide the directory structure these files are in. On *nix systems the `tree` utility can help with this. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593604/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I have edited my post and mentioned my project tree structure in the last.

Comment: Hi Vivek,
You are not supposed to run admin.py or views.py - manage.py is the only entrypoint that you should 'execute'. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually as I mentioned in views.py that I want to save my registration data in my "registerPerson" database but it is not performing the same. So if you can help me to figure out where I'm doing wrong in my code.