# how to import modules in python/django correctly?

Tags: python, django, import

Started learning Python recently and had a problem importing a model into django. I am trying to import a product model into Telegram bot handler but an error occurs.

**Below is how my directory structure looks like:**
[structure.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfwy0.png)

**Code:**

```
from jangoMiniShop.products.models import Product
```

**Error:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jangoMiniShop'
```

**Code:**

```
from ..products.models import Product
```

**Error:**

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError : Attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593604/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` file in `jangoMiniShop`? You can't use relative imports within the file you are executing (I presume you just ran `bot.py` or whatever you were running)

Comment: Yes, I had __init__.py, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another solution, created a command that launches the bot, a new directory appeared in the telegram folder:

```
|management/
|---- commands/
|-------- __init__.py
|-------- bot.py
|---- __init__.py
| __init__.py
```

Import started working in bot.py file:

```
from products.models import Product
```

P.S. The question remained open. Why `from products.models import Product` didn't work in the bot.py file in the root of the project created with the command `python manage.py startapp`