# How Do I get rid of this error:Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "C:\Program?

Tags: python, backend, fastapi

I keep trying to start my python backend with  `uvicorn main:app --reload` but I keep getting this error:

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\darkg\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\loginpage\\FastAP_BackEnd\\books']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [532] using StatReload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uvicorn.config import Config
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, re, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "C:\Users\darkg\OneDrive\Desktop\loginpage\FastAP_BackEnd\books\.\token.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import schemas
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I tried starting it with   `python -m uvicorn main:app --reload`
but I get this error  instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 146, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uvicorn.config import Config
  File "C:\Users\darkg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, re, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "C:\Users\darkg\OneDrive\Desktop\loginpage\FastAP_BackEnd\books\token.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import schemas
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Here is the main code

```
from . import models
from fastapi import FastAPI

from .database import engine
from .routers import books, users,authentication

app=FastAPI()
models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

app.include_router(books.router)
app.include_router(users.router)
app.include_router(authentication.router)
```

Here is my Code File Path If that helps solve the issue :
[Code File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuIJC.png)

I have tried everything but cant seem to find a way to fix this . I've redowloaded python. I've reinstalled every package, ive added paths to my packages, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am completely lost

Comment: Your problem is not Python, it's how you're referencing your modules in code (e.g, `models.py`, `database/engine.py`, etc.). Show your directory layout and look at similar problems like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874423/fastapi-importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769701/how-can-i-fix-the-relative-import-error-with-no-known-parent-package

Comment: I'm not sure how, but it seems like `C:\Users\darkg\OneDrive\Desktop\loginpage\FastAP_BackEnd\books` is in the python path so its `token.py`, which looks like its meant to be a submodule in the FastAP_BackEnd package is being imported instead of python's standard `token.py` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't know that the directory containing your modules (including `main.py`) is a package, therefore it can't properly locate imports. Create an empty `__init__.py` file in this directory to mark it as a *regular package*.

A rule of thumb is to mark all your directories that contain python modules as packages with this method.

There's another type of Python packages that may make your code **sometimes** work: *namespace packages*. They don't have to contain an `__init__.py` file. I recommend to just avoid them, unless you understand exactly what they're for and why you need them. [[Doc reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages)]

For a quick reference, search through the FastAPI documentation for "project file structure" (it may be called something similar).

Comment: All my directories  contain  the  __init__.py file already sadly.

Comment: I added my code file structure if that helps